# Different reputations on askubuntu-main ,meta-askubuntu & StackExchange-leagues!

Tags: support, reputation

At the same time, There are different reputations showing as following.

- Askubuntu main user

[image: mainask]

- Meta-Askubuntu user

[image: metaask]

- StackExchange Leagues

[image: sestates]

My question is Why it is showing different? (In other words Howmuch time takes to refresh?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's certainly a delay in the network reputation updates. This is largely because syncing this stuff in realtime is a complete nightmare in terms of network and data design. Cached updates are a way of life these days. They keep the internet alive.

The amount of time appears to vary. I don't know what the exact process is so I can't tell you if there's some form of object cache invalidation triggering after a timed period or if it's just a raw push at an interval.

I think the important thing to remember is that it doesn't really matter. Your reputation here is accurate and it will become accurate everywhere *eventually*.

Comment: The meta help page says it updates every hour.